# Two Loops and not connection to Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am a newbie in Node Js. I must work with Mysql.
I installed the mysql module and I must read the datas of a table in a 1st database and write in an other table of the 2nd database.
The issue: In the 2nd function calculBalance, the function build the query
but doens't execute the query. After finish the loop in the first function, this call the 2nd function and execute the query with bad parameters
I don't understand why I have 2 Loops and not one ??
Thanks for your help

The code :

```
router.post('/launch',syncData);

// First function
function syncData(req,res){
// First connection
//Fill an array
    for (var key in usersData){
        if (usersData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        // Call a 2nd function
            var resultCalculBalance=calculBalance(JSON.stringify(usersData[key]));
               console.log('Results  ->' + JSON.stringify(resultCalculBalance));
            }
        }
}
```

In a Second function, I connect to an 2nd Table of the First Database to search values
// Second function

```
function calculBalance(userData,req,res,err){
        var resultCalcBalance=0;
        var calcul_balance = "select sum(amount) as amount from ( SELECT sum(jjt.amount) as amount" +
            " FROM jos_joomrh_training_employee_hours_history jjt,jos_joomrh_event je,jos_joomrh_log jl " +
            " where je.id=jjt.event_id and je.id=jl.item_id and deleted_at is null " +
            " and user_id= " + userData.id + " and category_id= " + cat_id + " and date_format(je.date,'%Y-%m-%d')" + comp + dateJour +
            " union all SELECT sum(amount) as amount FROM jos_joomrh_training_employee_hours_history " +
            " where event_id is null and user_id=" + userData.id + " and category_id=" + cat_id + " ) as z group by amount ";
        console.log(calcul_balance);
        connectionMysql.query(calcul_balance,function(err,rows,fields){
            if(err){
                console.log('Error ' + err);
                return err;
            }
            console.log('calculData : ' + rows.length);
            if (rows.length != 0) {
    // somethings
return tabBalance;
}// end of the function
```

Comment: It's extremely hazardous to just jam user data in your query like that. The [`mysql2` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) supports prepared statements which I would strongly encourage you to use.

Comment: Thanks. Why it' hazardous ? I try mysql2.

Comment: If you're not careful, someone could [inject harmful data](http://bobby-tables.com/) but the most common problem is that a simple apostrophe ruins your query. Always escape properly to avoid problems like this, and the safest way to do that is prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you've got a function that makes a callback but doesn't accept one. That means your `syncData` function is finished before the query even runs.

What you need to do is allow `calculBalance` function to take a callback and then chain that back when it's time. The typical pattern:

```
function calculBalance(userData, cb) {
  db.query(sql, function(err,rows,fields) {
    if(err) {
      cb(err);
    }

    if (rows.length != 0) {
      cb(null, rows);
    }
  });
}
```

Anything you `return` from an asynchronous function goes nowhere, so don't even bother doing it. The only way to get data out of there is to pass it through the callback you've been given.

Now that this is fixed, you need to make the caller make an async call in a loop. I prefer solving this with a promise library, where you can do `Promise.all` or `Promise.map` on a list. If you're using callbacks, use the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I understand thé concept of CB but not promise. Inn this case. What do you suggestions ?

Comment: I prefer promises, they're easier to structure, but they do take some getting used to. If you're using callbacks, follow the example in the `async` library for waiting on multiple callbacks to complete: `async.map` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Like you I started learning nodejs recently. Coming from a serial development background, nodejs can be a paradigm shift mentally.

I found using promises allowed me to rely on control flows better than just callbacks. A promise resolves into a completion or an error. It is like a try - catch block in java. And I found that more helpful.

My two cents..

Comment: Thanks for pour feedback. Have you more information on promise, courses, link ....